# Как переставить таймер на серверное время js

Tags: javascript, таймер

Здравствуйте! Подскажите как переставить данный таймер на время UTC msk а не текущее на компьютере.

```js
var finaltime = Math.floor((new Date(2016,5,28,24,0,0)).getTime()/1000);
var timerId = window.setInterval( display, 100);
var el = document.getElementById("seconds");
var date = new Date;
function display() {
  var seconds = Math.floor((finaltime - (new Date()).getTime()/1000))
    ,minutes
    ,hours
    ,days
  ;
//date.getUTCFullYear(),date.getUTCMonth(),date.getUTCDate(),date.getUTCHours(),date.getUTCMinutes(),date.getUTCSeconds()
  if (seconds <= 0) {
  window.clearInterval( timerId);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'response.php?',
    data: 'name=Andrew',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#show').html(data);
    }
  });
  return;
  }

  days = Math.floor(seconds/86400);
  seconds = seconds % 86400;
  hours = zeropad( Math.floor( seconds / 3600));
  seconds = seconds % 3600;
  minutes = zeropad( Math.floor( seconds / 60));
  seconds = zeropad( seconds % 60);
  el.innerHTML = days + ' дней ' + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
function zeropad(n) {
  return n < 10 ? '0'+n : n.toString();
}
```

```html
<b id="seconds">0</b>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: _UTC msk_? это как?

Comment: Чтобы брало UTC и +3

Comment: используй везде **только** utc дату и проблемы не будет

Comment: Я не особо разбираюсь в js, не могли бы вы пример кода показать. 
Пытался сделать так `var seconds = Math.floor((finaltime - (new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(),date.getUTCMonth(),date.getUTCDate(),date.getUTCHours(),date.getUTCMinutes(),date.getUTCSeconds())).getTime()/1000))` но таймер просто стоит.

Comment: десять раз в секунду - не часто ли? Что у Вас на серверной стороне?

Comment: @Grundy ему нужен обратный отсчет до серверной полночи

Comment: @Igor, причем сервер в москве?:)

Comment: Мне нужно сделать таймер просто до определенного времени, когда время настанет передать переменную. Время должно быть серверное что бы в одно время передать, а код мне подсказали. Если я уменьшу setint до секунды таймер не будет отставать?

Comment: А Московское время как общее для всех.

Comment: @Богдан, все равно не совсем понятно, общее время это UTC - оно как раз одинаковое у всех и от него и надо отталкиваться. Пример можно в ответе увидеть, там таймер до полуночи по москве

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дата в яваскрипте хранится в UTC, поэтому достаточно создать конечную дату, как [время UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC), соответствующее времени по Москве, т.е.

Время МСК: 2016-06-28 21:00:00
Время UTC: 2016-06-28 18:00:00 (MSK-3 часа)

А далее все остается так как есть:

```js
var finaltime = Math.floor((Date.UTC(2116, 5, 28, 21, 0, 0)) / 1000);
var timerId = window.setInterval(display, 500);
var el = document.getElementById("seconds");

function display() {
  var seconds = Math.floor((finaltime - (new Date()).getTime() / 1000)),
    minutes, hours, days;
  if (seconds <= 0) {
    window.clearInterval(timerId);
    console.log('Done');
    return;
  }

  days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  seconds = seconds % 86400;
  hours = zeropad(Math.floor(seconds / 3600));
  seconds = seconds % 3600;
  minutes = zeropad(Math.floor(seconds / 60));
  seconds = zeropad(seconds % 60);
  el.innerHTML = days + ' дней ' + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

function zeropad(n) {
  return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n.toString();
}
```

```html
<b id="seconds">0</b>
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне это и было нужно. Прошу прощения кого запутал)

Comment: Каеф, теперь буду часто смотреть на эти оставшиеся дни и плакать, потому что не доживу до 2116

Comment: @Doofy, ты слишком пессимистично настроен :)